# Azure Wrong URL

Tags: azure

I have set up a website in azure that was working fine at

docketsweep.azurewebsites.net

but now it seems to load the wrong website. it is instead leading me to docketsnap.azurewebsites.net which of course is a different website but loads the correct URL

Does anyone who is savvy with azure know whats going on?

Comment: Both CNAMEs **docketsweep.azurewebsites.net** and **docketsnap.azurewebsites.net**  points to same IP. It is interesting. Are both of those yours?

Comment: They are yes. DocketSnap is another website hosted on Azure. What is strange though is that both websites earlier worked from there own independent URL's. Now both go to the same website.

Comment: It might be Azure DNS issue. You might want to contact Azure support team.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for you.

1. Turn off one site and try accessing the other one. And then try it the other way around.
2. Delete one site or both sites and recreate them and redeploy your code.
3. Contact Azure support:

   - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/